# Single Ruby Gem that parses BOTH xlsx and xls Excel files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xls, xlsx

I'm a bit frustrated with the gems out there. It seems like each one does one thing well but not others.

roo parses both xlsx and xls however it doesn't seem to read certain fields correctly and isn't working in each case I need it to.

spreadsheet gem doesn't parse xlsx

rubyXL doesn't parse xls files

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just combine the rubyXL gem and the spreadsheet gem if you're happy with the individual results both provide.

Comment: I'm sticking with roo since it parses both, and am having to implement extra logic around date and time fields depending on the format. Annoying, but do-able.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. It's not that uncommon to have change bits and pieces of your code to accommodate a gem.